how to use proxy for HttpsURLConnection
I tried using -
con.setRequestProperty(http.proxyHost", "xxxxxx");
con.setRequestProperty(http.proxyPort", "3128");
and also by another way -
String authHeader = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(new String(username + ":" + password).getBytes()))
con.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + authHeader);
but none of them worked.
Basically, I tested from below curl command and same I need to call from JAVA API -
curl --proxy http://username:password@hostname:port 

Possibly related
